# Json API isnt returning data

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a simple web API.

I have data going into the controller but I can't return it in the JSON API. I think the problem is returning the `IEnumerable` String.

BLL:

```
public IEnumerable<DTO.Gettod> Gettods()
    {
        DAL.todDataController tdc = new DAL.todDataController();
        return tdc.GetToddMobiles();
    }
```

Model:

```
public class TodViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<DTO.Gettod> ModelGetTod { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> Get()
 {
     BLL.todManager tm = new BLL.todManager();
     Models.TodViewModel tvm = new Models.TodViewModel();

     tvm.ModelGetTod = tm.Gettods().ToArray();
     return tvm as IEnumerable<string>;
 }
```

JSON file returns only a `Null` but I'm expecting an Array.

Comment: Could you please share what type is `tvm.ModelGetTod`?

Comment: It was Iemunbable but changed to IList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your controller to the below:

Edit: Changing the accepted answer to what worked for the user

```
public IHttpActionResult GetToddData () {
    BLL.todManager tm = new BLL.todManager ();
    Models.TodViewModel tvm = new Models.TodViewModel ();

    tvm.ModelGetTod = tm.Gettods ().ToList ();

    //HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, tvm.ModelGetTod as IEnumerable<string>);

    return Ok (tvm.ModelGetTod);
}
```

Also, debug and see if you are getting the expected values in the tvm.ModelGetTod property.

Comment: Hi Bruno, Thanks for your response.  Still getting Null unfortunately.  The values are being carried through right up until the controller.  Not sure what is stopping it.

Comment: Is the tvm.ModelGetTod populated? Try returning the type IActionResult from the controller method and return Ok(tvm.ModelGetTod as IEnumerable<string>);

Comment: Although your solution has worked in other applications.

Comment: tvm.ModelGetTod is populated.

Comment: Is this a MVC or WebApi2 project?

Comment: Web APi project.

Comment: I think I know what is happening, tvm.ModelGetTod is not convertible to IEnumerable<string>. ModelGetTod is of type IEnumerable<DTO.Gettod> and cannot be converted to string. If you change tvm.ModelGetTod as IEnumerable<string>; to (IEnumerable<string>)tvm.ModelGetTod in the return line, you will see that it throws an exception. You are converting to the wrong type.

Comment: What is the property inside DTO.Gettod that holds the string you want to retrieve?

Comment: Hi Bruno, I fixed it by implementing both of your suggestions.  I changed removed iEnumerable and changed to the action to IHttpActionResult.

Comment: Glad it helped, I'll update the answer to the final one you posted below

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The Correct Code is below, crediting: Bruno in the below answer:

```
  public IHttpActionResult GetToddData()
            {
            BLL.todManager tm = new BLL.todManager();
            Models.TodViewModel tvm = new Models.TodViewModel();

            tvm.ModelGetTod = tm.Gettods().ToList();

            //HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, tvm.ModelGetTod as IEnumerable<string>);

            return Ok(tvm.ModelGetTod);
        }
```